# rel="tooltip", is it bad practice?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, w3c

In the bootstrap documentation for tooltips, it uses `<a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="first tooltip">hover over me</a>`. Tooltips are just cosmetic though. Not css style but just a bit of JS to change how a title attribute is presented.

The "rel" attribute is meant to be used to tell a bot (such as google) about the nature of a link. The options are alternate, author, bookmark, help, license, next, nofollow, noreferrer, prefetch, prev, search, and tag.

Is it not bad practice to use `rel = "tooltip"` since tooltip is cosmetic, says nothing about the nature of the link, and isn't otherwise bot or browser interpret-able?

Comment: Note this will be changed in Bootstrap 2.3 ([source](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/6380)).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By using `rel="tooltip"` your document **won't validate** by the W3C web standards.

You will get this error from the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/):

> *Bad value tooltip for attribute rel on element a: Not an absolute IRI.
>   The string tooltip is not a registered keyword or absolute URL.*

It would be better, **identifying a tooltip** link **with a class** like:
`<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="first tooltip">hover over me</a>`

- However, the rel attribute is not used by the browser in any way, as
  you already mentioned, but it **may influence your ranking in search
  engines**. [Google suggests](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=100782) to validate your documents and
  to "write good, clean HTML".
- The rel attribute may also be
  interesting for **accessibility** tools like screen readers.

Comment: @Bryan Ash answer is fine for tooltip.

Answer (score 11):

Or easily you can replace `rel` with the `data-rel` attribute (which is absolutely valid).

Example:

```
$("a[data-rel]").tooltip();
```

Comment: +1 This has many benefits and separates it from the class attribute; I think this is the best alternative solution.

Answer (score 2):

The Bootstrap [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) suggests using `data-toggle="tooltip"`, e.g.:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>
```

and enabling them with:

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```